# how to compare two rows and get the result via index in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Dataframe

```
  Day Value
1  Mon   0
2  Mon   1
3  Fri   1
4  Mon   1
5  Mon   1
6  Mon   1
7  Mon   0
8  Tue   1
9  Tue   1
```

And I want to find a row having two consecutive 1 by Grouping with Day column.

**Expected Output:**

```
  Day  Value
5 Mon   1
6 Mon   1
9 Tue   1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering:

```
m = df['Value'].eq(1)
s = df['Day'].ne(df['Day'].shift()).cumsum()
df = df[s[m].duplicated() & m]
print (df)
   Day  Value
5  Mon      1
6  Mon      1
9  Tue      1
```

**Details**:

First create consecutive Series with [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
print (df['Day'].ne(df['Day'].shift()).cumsum())
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    4
9    4
Name: Day, dtype: int32
```

then filter by `1` values in `Value`:

```
print (s[m])
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    3
8    4
9    4
Name: Day, dtype: int32
```

And get [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for all dupes of helper `Series` called `s`:

```
print (s[m].duplicated())
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
8    False
9     True
Name: Day, dtype: bool
```

Last chain with bitwise AND by `&` for mask with same size like original:

```
print (s[m].duplicated() & m)
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
9     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with pandas as a data structure so I can't provide working code, but this would be my approach on this problem:

```
previous_value = 0
all_correct_rows = []
for i in data_row:
   if current_value == 1 and previous_value == 1:
      all_correct_rows.append(current_row)
   previous_value = current_value
```

Where `previous_value` and `current_value` are the values in the day column.